# thread-safety proxy with libcurl

Tags: c++, proxy, thread-safety, singleton, libcurl

```
    #pragma once

    #ifndef __CURL_CURL_H
    #include "curl.h"
    #endif

    #ifndef __CURL_EASY_H
    #include "easy.h"
    #endif

    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <memory>
    #include <string>

    namespace CommUnit
    {
        enum ERR_PROXY
        {
            ERR_CURL_INIT_FAILED = 0xA0,
            ERR_SET_PROXY_FAILED = 0xA1,
        };


        class MyProxy
        {
        public:
            static MyProxy & GetInstance()  //Meyers' Singlton
            {
                static MyProxy ProxySigleton;
                return ProxySigleton;
            }
        public:
            /*
            * @bref:Get request
            * @param[in] sUrl:Access URL
            * @param[in] sProxyIp:Proxy IP
            * @param[in] uProxyPort:Proxy Port
            * @param[in] uTimeOut:Time out
            * @param[in] isSSL:HTTPS true,else false
            * @param[out] sRetContent:Return the URL content
            */
            uint32_t Get(const std::string &sUrl,
                const std::string& sProxyIp,
                uint32_t uProxyPort,
                uint32_t uTimeOut,
                bool isSSL,
                std::string &sRetContent);

        private:
            MyProxy();                              //Constructor hidden
            MyProxy(MyProxy const &);               //Copy-Constructor hidden
            MyProxy & operator= (MyProxy const &);  //Assign operator hidden
            ~MyProxy();                             //Destructor hidden

            inline void _setCurlopt(CURL *pCurl,
                const std::string &sUrl,
                std::string &sWriterData,
                const uint32_t uTimeOut,
                bool isSSL);

            //Callback function, write data to writerData
            static int Writer(char *data,
                uint32_t size,
                uint32_t nmemb,
                std::string *writerData);


        private:
            std::string m_sErrMsg;
            static char s_ErrBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
            static const uint32_t m_MAXBUF = 2 * 1024 * 1024 - 128; 
        };
    }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "MyProxy.h"
#include "Log.h"
#include <curl.h>

using namespace CommUnit;

char MyProxy::s_ErrBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE] = { 0 };


MyProxy::MyProxy(void)
{
    CURLcode oCURLcode = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    if (oCURLcode != CURLE_OK)
    {
        Log("ERR: %s curl_init failed!", __func__);
    }
}

MyProxy::~MyProxy(void)
{
    curl_global_cleanup();
}


uint32_t MyProxy::Get(const std::string &sUrl,
    const std::string& sProxyIp,
    uint32_t uProxyPort,
    uint32_t uTimeOut,
    bool isSSL,
    std::string &sRetContent)
{
    sRetContent.clear();
    CURL *pCurl = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode oCURLcode;
    if (nullptr == pCurl)
    {
        Log("ERR: %s curl_easy_init failed!", __func__);
        return ERR_CURL_INIT_FAILED;
    }
    _setCurlopt(pCurl, sUrl, sRetContent, uTimeOut, isSSL);
    if (0 == sProxyIp.length()|| 0 == uProxyPort)
    {
        Log("ERR: %s SetProxy: ProxyIp [%s], ProxyPort[%u] failed",__func__, sProxyIp.c_str(), uProxyPort);
        return ERR_SET_PROXY_FAILED;
    }
    Log("INFO: %s SetProxy: ProxyIp [%s], ProxyPort[%u] failed", __func__, sProxyIp.c_str(), uProxyPort);
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_PROXY, sProxyIp.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, uProxyPort);
    int iTimes = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        oCURLcode = curl_easy_perform(pCurl);
        if (oCURLcode != CURLE_OK && ++iTimes < 3)
            usleep(5);
        else
            break;
    }
    if (oCURLcode != CURLE_OK)
    {
        Log("ERR: %s curl_easy_perform failed!", __func__);
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(pCurl);
    return oCURLcode;
}

void MyProxy::_setCurlopt(CURL *pCurl,
    const std::string &sUrl,
    std::string &sWriterData,
    const uint32_t uTimeOut,
    bool isSSL)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, s_ErrBuffer);
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_URL, sUrl.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, uTimeOut);
    Log("INFO: %s Set Url:[%s],TimeOut:[%d]", __func__, sUrl.c_str(), uTimeOut);
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, MyProxy::Writer);
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &sWriterData);

    //Skip peer and hostname verification
    if (isSSL)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    }
}


int MyProxy::Writer(char *data,
    uint32_t size,
    uint32_t nmemb,
    std::string *writerData)
{
    if (writerData == nullptr)
    {
        Log("ERR: %s writerData is null!", __func__);
        return 0;
    }
    int len = size * nmemb;
    if ((writerData->size() + len) > m_MAXBUF)
    {
        Log("ERR: %s writerData size over MAXBUF!", __func__);
        return 0;
    }
    writerData->append(data, len);
    return len;
}
```

I want to realize a proxy with libcurl, which can get the content of given url(https). Morever,  it need to be thread-safety.
But when I created 200 threads with pthreads to test my code, an segment fault occured sometimes.
How can I solve this problem?
Is there a relation with the sRetContent(std::string)?
Thanks!

Errmsg:
double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0ac72840 ***
Segmentation fault

Comment: Start with learning how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that libcurl is not thread-safe if you are using https (and it looks like you are) due to the fact that it is using underlying ssl libraries. [See libcurl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html#Multi-threading) and [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html#DESCRIPTION) for more info.

If your libcurl was compiled with OpenSSL for example then you have to initialize a few callback functions or you could run into issues. This is the sort of thing you need to do (compiles on Windows):

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>

void win32_locking_callback(int mode, int type, const char *file, int line)
{
    if (mode & CRYPTO_LOCK)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(lock_cs[type],INFINITE);
    }
    else
    {
        ReleaseMutex(lock_cs[type]);
    }
}

void thread_setup(void)
{
    int i;

    lock_cs=(HANDLE*)OPENSSL_malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() * sizeof(HANDLE));
    for (i=0; i<CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++)
    {
        lock_cs[i]=CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,NULL);
    }

    CRYPTO_set_locking_callback((void (*)(int,int,const char *,int))win32_locking_callback);
}

void thread_cleanup(void)
{
    int i;

    CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(NULL);
    for (i=0; i<CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++)
        CloseHandle(lock_cs[i]);
    OPENSSL_free(lock_cs);
}
```

I always call thread_setup() after my call to curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL)
and then thread_cleanup() right before my call to curl_global_cleanup().

I use this sort of code with libcurl often in load test scenarios and have never run into any issues. If you continue to run into problems, it is not libcurl, but something not being done properly in your code.

Comment: I think libcurl is thread safe now using httpS. But only not the global init and cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

libcurl is thread-safe as long as you play by [the rules](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html#Multi-threading)